# How to read click house tables from Python Azure function?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I need to read the tables from click house via Python Azure function, I am able to read the tables from my local system but not able to read from Python Azure Function.

What I tried:

```
import clickhouse_connect
client = clickhouse_connect.get_client(host=host, port=port, username='XXXX', password='XXXX', database = 'MYDB')
df = client.query_df('SELECT TOP (10) * FROM MYTABLE')
print(df)
```

The above is working from my local system, but when I am running the same code from azure function then I am getting the following error

```
import clickhouse_connect
client = clickhouse_connect.get_client(host=host, port=port, username='XXXX', password='XXXX', database = 'MYDB')
df = client.query_df('SELECT TOP (10) * FROM MYTABLE') <-- Error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'array'
```

Comment: What is the stack trace of the error?  I don't know of anyone trying to do this in Azure before, but network security and the available Python version have caused issues in AWS Lambdas, for example.

Comment: Also, what clickhouse-connect and pandas version are you using?

Comment: I am using Python ==3.8 and clickhouse-connect 0.6.6

Comment: Can you get the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you have generated the `requirements.txt` which includes all of the information of the modules (in your case, `clickhouse-connect 0.6.6`). When you deploy the function to azure, it will install the modules by the `requirements.txt` automatically.